# AS3 - Make the screen flash for half a second

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, effects

What I want to do is:

After colliding with an [object], I want the screen to flash for about half of a second. I have tried `for loops` and `while loops` but they seem to not work. I have no idea how I should program this.

I've been trying to figure out how to do this since I'v been making the game so it would be helpful if someone could help me.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something that involves time.   loops all run in a thread which doesn't pause for time - which is why they don't work.

Here is how you could do this with an AS3 `Timer` (let's say this code runs right after you've determined there's been a collision)

```
function flashScreen():void {
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(50, 10); //run the timer every 50 milliseconds, 10 times (eg the whole timer will run for half a second giving you a tick 10 times)

    var flash:Shape = new Shape(); //a white rectangle to cover the whole screen.
    flash.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
    flash.graphics.drawRect(0,0,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
    flash.visible = false;
    stage.addChild(flash);

    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent):void {
        //we've told AS3 to run this every 50 milliseconds

        flash.visible = !flash.visible; //toggle visibility
        //if(Timer(e.currentTarget).currentCount % 2 == 0){ } //or you could use this as a fancy way to do something every other tick
    });

    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(e:TimerEvent):void {
        //the timer has run 10 times, let's stop this flashing madness.
        stage.removeChild(flash);
    });

    timer.start();
}
```

Other ways you can do this are with `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, a Tweening library,and an `ENTER_FRAME` event handler.

Comment: How much of the stuff that is not in a function, can I put in a function?

Comment: You could put it all into one function if you really wanted to (using inline functions for the tick and timerDone methods).  would you like me re-write it so it's all encapsulated into one function?

Comment: That would be very useful and very kind of you if you did.

Comment: Indeed I did.  Calling `flashScreen()` will flash the screen.  Tweak the `50` value to make it flash faster or slower.

Comment: Thank you so much ^u^ your a life saver.